# Open Standard Prolog Knowledge Bases

Tags: logic, knowledge-representation, logic-programming, prolog

Are there any standard Prolog knowledge bases available anywhere that have the same purpose as Cyc, namely to encode generally accepted common sense and human knowledge?

Typically containing generally accepted facts such as the ones given at

http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/CS1023/readings/prolog.html

Comment: For what purpose?  What are your requirements?  What search have you done?  A 'knowledge base' is typically crafted for a particular application domain and is very specific to a particular application domain, so asking for "standard knowledge bases" without specifying the application domain (or purpose for which you'd put it to use) doesn't make any sense -- and is overly broad.

Comment: I want to add inference algorithms on top of very generic knowledge graphs such as ConceptNet, NELL, Yago, etc.